# How to track events from WhatsApp Stickers package app?

Tags: android, whatsapp, whatsapp-stickers

I've created a stickers pack using [WhatsApp/stickers sample app](https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers)  and wondering if there is a way how to track individual stickers usage events within main WhatsApp application (if someone used sticker in conversation). I'm using [MS App Center SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/) for collecting Analytics but built-in events provides information only about installation.

Comment: Any leads??? I am looking for the same...

Comment: Nope. So far I'm under impression it's not possible by design - stickers are being imported into the main app and its metrics are not accessible for stickers app developers.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible at the moment. But we will keep this need in mind when improving.

Comment: I really hope stickers are not and will never be another tool to track whatsapp usage.